# Header cover image height shortens after clicking on navbar link

Tags: html, css

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: black;
  background-image: url('../../files/header-image.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: $base-font;
}
```

I set cover image for header, height 100vh. Navbar is inside header but fixed position. When i click on some of the navbar links it leads to other sections on the page (it is one page website), and when i scroll back my cover image got shorter for 60px (height of navbar). Why is this happening?

Comment: when element has `position:fixed` it positioned relative to body and do not affect to other elements positions

Comment: Try to take down the "position: relative" of your header, also try to use a "px" value for your header height.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle so we can try and fix it that way? With the code you supplied we can't recreate it ourselves

Comment: i just needed to add overflow hidden.